# How to remove duplicate rows while keeping only first row based on duplicate data in B & C columns. Rows to be checked sequentially

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet that is populated with end of day portfolio data in my 'portfolio history' sheet, so I require to delete rows where there is duplicate data in column B & C while keeping the first row with the oldest data.(eg duplicate data '123' in column B row 19,20,21 & '4567' column C row 19,20,21. I only require first entry in this case for row 19,rows 20, 21 to be deleted).The rows need to be checked sequentially for duplicates in column B & C. How would I do this? Thanks!!!

Image https://photos.app.goo.gl/7Ufowk4r7K9Gdpsw1

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function removeDupesInBAndC(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('portfolio history');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var dupesA=[];
  var delA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    var s=vA[i][1].toString() + vA[i][2].toString();
    var idx=dupesA.indexOf(s);
    if(idx>-1){
      delA.push(idx);
    }else{
      dupesA.push(s);
    }
  }
  for(var i=delA.length-1;i>-1;i--){
    sh.deleteRow(i+1);
  }
}
```